# Applying two scopes in one ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

My **Program** model has this:

```
has_many :registry_patient_counts
scope :salary_and_bonus, 
  :joins => :registry_patient_counts,
  :order => "patient_count_percentage DESC"
```

and this works well when I start simple an baby steps with my controller which is this:

```
programs = 
  Program.includes([:registry_patient_counts])
    .salary_and_bonus.where('organization_id = 1')
    .limit(2)
```

but my ultimate controller should look like this ( How it looks like without having scopes )

```
@programs = Program.includes(
  [:registry_patient_counts, measures: :measures_off_targets])
  .where('organization_id = 1')
  .limit(2)
```

so notice it has a  `measures: :measures_off_targets` extra in it. 
So similarly between measures and measures_off_targets I want to define a similar scope as the previous one .... but then I don't understand how to type both of those scopes in the controller?

---

**EDIT: So this is what we have so far by following the answer below:**

In Program.rb:

```
scope :rpc,   includes(:registry_patient_counts).order => "patient_count_percentage DESC"

scope :msr, includes(measures: :measures_off_targets)
```

And controller query looks like this:

```
@programs2 = Program.rpc.msr.where('organization_id: 1').limit(2)
```

where the error that RubyMine shows in the IDE is that "cannot find msr"
If I ignore that and go to browser, still in the Rail console I get a "Error 500, bad request" and nothing back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain scopes and includes.

```
scope :rpc, includes(:registry_patient_counts)
scope :msr, includes(measures: :measures_off_targets)

@programs = Program.rpc.msr.where(organization_id: 1).limit(2)

# Equivalent to
@programs = Program.includes(
  [:registry_patient_counts, measures: :measures_off_targets])
  .where(organization_id: 1)
  .limit(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. It looks much easier to read now. And thanks for answering the question actually. Let me quickly try and see how it goes.

Comment: Hmm, in the new syntax where can I put the ":order => "patient_count_percentage DESC" statements ? I put it after includes but it gave me error saying wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Or if we can write a new scope for the second part of a separate query, I can use that too, basically this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183785/scope-that-has-three-levels-deep-joins

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but you can put the order clause into a scope like this: 
`scope :foo, includes(:something).order("whatnot DESC")`
You could of course do a separate scope for the ordering, and just chain that to the query, too.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did that now but at the best case there are some syntax error going on...at the worst case we are just doing it wrong. Let me "EDIT" my post and put the codes we have written so far. It is easier to read code in the question than in the comments.

Comment: Yup, you've got a syntax error. You should look into what you're actually doing. They way you wrote it, you're treating `order` as a hash-key. But it's a method. You should write `[stuff...].order("something DESC")`

Comment: Maybe I wound up sounding a bit whiny in the last comment, but all I want is to really recommend you to think about what the syntax _actually_ means. It's been a huge help for me! :)