# Scope that has three levels deep joins

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

My `Program` table has many `Measures`
My `Measure` table has many `Targets`
My `Target` table has a column called "**money**"

My ActiveRecord query looks like this:

```
@programs2 = Program.includes([measures: :target]).where('organization_id = 1').limit(2)
```

I want to define a scope such that the query can return top Programs that their target.money value is the lowest.  So I need to write a scope and apply it to that query but How and Where in the model should I define that scope,  something like this? Well this won't work but that's as much as I know.

```
scope :top5, :joins => [:measures, :targets]  ,  :order => "money DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the target.money of a Program, the sum of all Targets.money of all Measures for this Program ?

You can try something like:

```
Target.order_by( :money => :desc ).map{|target| target.measure }.map{|measure| measure.program }.uniq
```

Good luck

Comment: target.money  : no it is just a number, I made up some table and field names for posting on SO , so they may not make very sense in practice.